# How to use "MatchEvaluator" function to reduce coding?

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm trying to search the regular expression `pattern` and, if it matches, find whether the value of that pattern exists inside any tag of the form `<sec id="sec123">` in a file. If it does, I want to replace it with `result1`. I think it can be done with the `MatchEvaluator` function, but I can't figure out how to apply it.

I'm new to VB.NET (and programming in general) and really don't know what to do. This is what I've tried so far:

```
Dim pattern As String="(?<=rid=\"sec)(\\d+)(?=\">)"
Dim r As Regex = New Regex(pattern)
Dim m As Match = r.Match(input)
If (m.Success) Then
    Dim x As String=" id=""sec"+ pattern +""""
    Dim r2 As Regex = New Regex(x)
    Dim m2 As Match = r2.Match(input)
    If (m2.Success) Then
        Dim tgPat AsString="<xref ref-type="section" rid=""sec + pattern +"">(\w+) (\d+)</xref>"
        Dim tgRep As String= "$1 $2"
        Dim tgReg As New Regex(tgPat)
        Dim result1 As String = tgReg.Replace(input, tgRep)
    Else
    EndIf
EndIf
Next
```

sample input:

```
<sec id="sec1">
<p>"You fig. 23 did?" I <xref ref-type="section" rid="sec12">section 12</a> asked, surprised.</p>
<p>"There are always better terms <xref ref-type="section" rid="sec6">section 6</a>, Richard!" my mom said sharply.</p>
<p>I <xref ref-type="section" rid="sec2">section 2</a> stood. I <xref ref-type="section" rid="sec2">section 2</a> had to hurry if I <xref ref-type="section" rid="sec1">section 1</a> was going to get to work on time.
<fig id="fig4">
<caption><p>I'm confused</p></caption>
</fig> 
</p>
<p>Turning to face her, I <xref ref-type="section" rid="sec2">section 2</a> walked backward. "I"ve seriously got to get ready. Why don"t we get together for lunch and talk more then?"</p>
<sec id="sec2">
<p>"You fig. 23 can"t be""</p>
<p>I <xref ref-type="section" rid="sec4">section 4</a> adored the Art Deco elegance of the Chrysler Building. I <xref ref-type="section" rid="sec2">section 2</a> could pinpoint my place on the island in relation to the posit table 9ion of the Empire State Building.</p>
<p>I <xref ref-type="section" rid="sec1">section 1</a> felt Gideon before I <xref ref-type="section" rid="sec1">section 1</a> saw him, my entire body humming wit table 9h awareness as he stepped out of the Bentley, which had pulled up behind the Benz.</p>
</sec>
</sec>
```

expected output:

```
<sec id="sec1">
<p>"You fig. 23 did?" I **section 12** asked, surprised.</p>
<p>"There are always better terms **section 6**, Richard!" my mom said sharply.</p>
<p>I <xref ref-type="section" rid="sec2">section 2</a> stood. I <xref ref-type="section" rid="sec2">section 2</a> had to hurry if I <xref ref-type="section" rid="sec1">section 1</a> was going to get to work on time.
<fig id="fig4">
<caption><p>I'm confused</p></caption>
</fig> 
</p>
<p>Turning to face her, I <xref ref-type="section" rid="sec2">section 2</a> walked backward. "I"ve seriously got to get ready. Why don"t we get together for lunch and talk more then?"</p>
<sec id="sec2">
<p>"You fig. 23 can"t be""</p>
<p>I **section 4** adored the Art Deco elegance of the Chrysler Building. I <xref ref-type="section" rid="sec2">section 2</a> could pinpoint my place on the island in relation to the posit table 9ion of the Empire State Building.</p>
<p>I <xref ref-type="section" rid="sec1">section 1</a> felt Gideon before I <xref ref-type="section" rid="sec1">section 1</a> saw him, my entire body humming wit table 9h awareness as he stepped out of the Bentley, which had pulled up behind the Benz.</p>
</sec>
</sec>
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're after here. Could you please post a minimal input string and the desired output that you want from it.

Comment: You are parsing an XML and that is better done with an XML parser. After accessing  the sec tags with id=sec123 you may modify the text easily.

Comment: @FloatingKiwi I've updated my question with a sample input and desired output, the items inside "**" are the tags that should be removed as there are no id="sec12", id="sec4" and id="sec6" inside any of the tags `<sec id="secX">` in the entire file. Hopefully you will understand it now?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have no knowledge of how to use XML parser in Vb.net, that is why I'm trying to do it using normal text string manipulation techniques...

Answer (score 0):

I've replaced my initial solution with one which uses XElement as your data isn't as straightforward as I initially thought.

```
    Dim input = XElement.Parse(data)
    Dim sections = input.Descendants("sec").ToDictionary(Function(s) s.@id, Function(s) s)
    Dim xrefs = input.Descendants("xref").ToLookup(Function(s) s.@rid, Function(s) s)

    For Each group In xrefs
        Dim section As XElement
        If sections.TryGetValue(group.Key, section) Then
            For Each xref In group
                xref.ReplaceWith(section)
            Next
        End If
    Next
    Dim output = input.ToString()
```

I think this does what you're after although I don't trust your data as Section2 seems to be recursive. Have a try and see what you think anyway. Steps:

1. Parse the xml
2. Extract the sections and key them by id in a dictionary
3. Extract the xrefs (multiple with same key) add them by id to a Lookup
4. For each xref check if it has a section. If it does then replace it.
5. Extract the result.