# Modify linking tags after analyzing some data in a file

Tags: regex, vb.net

I want to make a program which will look for a expression `<disp-formula id="deqn(\d+)-(\d+)">` in files and if there is one or more match, then it will search the whole file for expressions in the form `<xref ref-type="disp-formula" rid="deqnX">(X)</xref>` or `<xref ref-type="disp-formula" rid="deqnX">X</xref>` where **X** ranges from the first **(\d+)** to the last **(\d+)** and replace it to `<xref ref-type="disp-formula" rid="deqn$1-$2">(X)</xref>` or `<xref ref-type="disp-formula" rid="deqn$1-$2">X</xref>`

sample input:

```
<sec id="sec1">
<para>In addition, many of you will be glad to hear that <xref ref-type="disp-formula" rid="deqn1">(1)</xref> Visual Basic is now a fully object-oriented programming language <xref ref-type="disp-formula" rid="deqn3">(3)</xref>-<xref ref-type="disp-formula" rid="deqn5">(5)</xref>, with the inclusion of the long sought-after class inheritance, as well as other OOP features.</para>
</sec>
<para>In this chapter, you'll see how Visual Basic has evolved eq. <xref ref-type="disp-formula" rid="deqn1">1</xref>  into the VB .NET language of today and get some sense of how and why VB .NET is different from previous versions of Visual Basic.</para>
<sec id="sec1a">
<para>How had I ever managed living without him?
<disp-formula id="deqn1-2">$$\phi=a+b-c^2$$</disp-formula></para>
<para>Gideon Cross. <xref ref-type="figure" rid="fig2">Figure 2</xref>, table 3.</para>
<para>This chapter surveys some of the new features of the .NET Framework <xref ref-type="disp-formula" rid="deqn2">(2)</xref>, <xref ref-type="disp-formula" rid="deqn5">(5)</xref> that most impact the  VB developer. These include namespaces, the Common Language Runtime (CLR), and assemblies.</para>
<para>The third and final section, Part III, consists of the following appendixes:
<disp-formula id="deqn3-5">$$m=a+b-c$$</disp-formula>
</para>
</sec>
</sec>
<sec id="sec2">
<label>2.</label>
<disp-formula id="deqn6">$$\cal {X}=y=1$$</disp-formula>
<para>The switch…case Statement.</para>
<para>A discussion of language changes <xref ref-type="disp-formula" rid="deqn6">(6)</xref> from VB 6 to VB .NET.</para>
<para>A list of VB .NET intrinsic constants, as well as VB .NET enumerations and their members.</para>
</sec>
```

desired output:

```
<sec id="sec1">
<para>In addition, many of you will be glad to hear that <xref ref-type="disp-formula" rid="deqn1-2">(1)</xref> Visual Basic is now a fully object-oriented programming language <xref ref-type="disp-formula" rid="deqn3-5">(3)</xref> and <xref ref-type="disp-formula" rid="deqn3-5">(5)</xref>, with the inclusion of the long sought-after class inheritance, as well as other OOP features.</para>
</sec>
<para>In this chapter, you'll see how Visual Basic has evolved eq. <xref ref-type="disp-formula" rid="deqn1-2">1</xref>  into the VB .NET language of today and get some sense of how and why VB .NET is different from previous versions of Visual Basic.</para>
<sec id="sec1a">
<para>How had I ever managed living without him?
<disp-formula id="deqn1-2">$$\phi=a+b-c^2$$</disp-formula></para>
<para>Gideon Cross. <xref ref-type="figure" rid="fig2">Figure 2</xref>, table 3.</para>
<para>This chapter surveys some of the new features of the .NET Framework <xref ref-type="disp-formula" rid="deqn1-2">(2)</xref>, <xref ref-type="disp-formula" rid="deqn3-5">(5)</xref> that most impact the  VB developer. These include namespaces, the Common Language Runtime (CLR), and assemblies.</para>
<para>The third and final section, Part III, consists of the following appendixes:
<disp-formula id="deqn3-5">$$m=a+b-c$$</disp-formula>
</para>
</sec>
</sec>
<sec id="sec2">
<label>2.</label>
<disp-formula id="deqn6">$$\cal {X}=y=1$$</disp-formula>
<para>The switch…case Statement.</para>
<para>A discussion of language changes <xref ref-type="disp-formula" rid="deqn6">(6)</xref> from VB 6 to VB .NET.</para>
<para>A list of VB .NET intrinsic constants, as well as VB .NET enumerations and their members.</para>
</sec>
```

This is what I've tried so far

```
 Dim targetDirectory As String = TextBox1.Text
        Dim txtFilesArray As String() = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory, "*.txt")
        For Each txtFile In txtFilesArray
            Dim input As String = File.ReadAllText(txtFile)
            Dim disp As New Regex("<disp-formula id=""deqn(\d+)-(\d+)"">")
            Dim match As Match = disp.Match(input)
            If disp.Matches() Then
                Dim a As Integer = match.Groups(1).Value
                Dim b As Integer = match.Groups(2).Value
                For Each c=a to b in input
                        Dim xref As New Regex("<xref[^>]+rid=""(?<id>deqn\d+-\d+)""[^>]*>(?<content>[^<]+)</xref>")
                    Dim result As String = xref.Replace(input, Function(xyz)
                                                                  ???????
                                                               End Function)
                Next

                File.WriteAllText(txtFile, result)
            End If
        Next
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Just a comment, not a solution: can you narrow your question down? Additionally, a parser might be more appropriate in your situation.

Comment: I answered a similar question a couple of weeks back. Using an xml parser is far easier. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38938984/how-to-use-matchevaluator-function-to-reduce-coding/38940068#38940068

Comment: @FloatingKiwi I'm not familiar with xml parsing techniques, thats why I'm trying to achieve it without using xml parsing techniques. I don't mind if the code gets a bit big...

Comment: @Jan Do you have any suggestions on how can I narrow the question down and still make people understand what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the commented UltraEdit script (language JavaScript) which I wrote for you or someone else of your company for nearly exactly same task.

For additional information visit in [UltraEdit - Scripts](https://www.ultraedit.com/forums/viewforum.php?f=52) forum the topic [Script to modify linking tags](https://www.ultraedit.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=52&t=16822).

There are some small differences:

1. The tag `<formula` in UE forum is here now `<disp-formula`.
2. The `id`/`rid` attribute value `dqn` in UE forum is here now `deqn`.
3. The `ref-type` attribute value `d-formula` in UE forum is here now `disp-formula`.
4. The reference number in `xref` element was always enclosed in parentheses in UE forum and here is only optionally enclosed in parentheses.

The script code as posted by me in UltraEdit forum was adapted by me for those 4 small differences whereby each reference value in reformatted file is always enclosed in parentheses.

```js
function outputDebugInfo(sDebugInfo)
{
//    UltraEdit.outputWindow.write(sDebugInfo);
}

if (UltraEdit.document.length > 0)  // Is any file opened?
{
    // Define environment for this script.
    UltraEdit.insertMode();
    UltraEdit.columnModeOff();

    // Define from which file to read the formula identifiers.
    var oFormulaDoc = UltraEdit.activeDocument;

    var nRefIndex;
    var nFormulaIndex;
    var anFormulas = new Array();

    // Select the entire file with the formula identifiers.
    // There is nothing selected if the file is an empty file.
    oFormulaDoc.selectAll();
    if (oFormulaDoc.isSel())
    {
        // Get all formula identifiers with a single number and convert each
        // number from string to integer. The formula identifier numbers are
        // stored in a two dimensional array. On a single number first and
        // second number are identical in the two columns in the current row.
        var asFormulas = oFormulaDoc.selection.match(/<disp-formula id="deqn\d+"/g);
        if (asFormulas != null)
        {
            for (nFormulaIndex = 0; nFormulaIndex < asFormulas.length; nFormulaIndex++)
            {
                var nFormula = parseInt(asFormulas[nFormulaIndex].replace(/^.+deqn(\d+).$/,"$1"),10);
                anFormulas.push([nFormula,nFormula]);
            }
        }

        // Get all formula identifiers with a number range and convert
        // the two numbers of each number range from string to integer.
        // The FROM number is stored in first column of formula row and
        // the TO number is stored in second column.
        var asFormulas  = oFormulaDoc.selection.match(/<disp-formula id="deqn\d+-\d+"/g);
        if (asFormulas != null)
        {
            for (nFormulaIndex = 0; nFormulaIndex < asFormulas.length; nFormulaIndex++)
            {
                var nFrom = parseInt(asFormulas[nFormulaIndex].replace(/^.+deqn(\d+)-.+$/,"$1"),10);
                var nTo = parseInt(asFormulas[nFormulaIndex].replace(/^.+deqn\d+-(\d+).$/,"$1"),10);
                anFormulas.push([nFrom,nTo]);
            }
        }

        // Cancel the selection and move caret to top of file.
        oFormulaDoc.top();
    }

    // The formula references can be only checked and updated
    // if there was before at least 1 formula identifier found.
    if (anFormulas.length > 0)
    {
        // Dumps formular identifiers table to output window.
        // var_dump(anFormulas);

        var nRefsFound = 0;     // Counts the number of found formula reference sequences.
        var nRefsModified = 0;  // Counts the number of modified formula reference sequences.

        // Define start tag with the attributes and end tag of a formula reference.
        var sRefStart = '<xref ref-type="disp-formula" rid="deqn';
        var sRefEnd   = '</xref>';

        // Define some search and replace strings used in the main loop below.
        var sFindRefs = sRefStart + '[\\d\\-]+">.+?' + sRefEnd + '(?:[\\s,-]*(?:&#x2013;\\s*)?' +
                             sRefStart + '[\\d\\-]+">.+?' + sRefEnd + ')*';
        outputDebugInfo("sFindRefs  = " + sFindRefs);

        var sReplRange = ')' + sRefEnd + '#' + sRefStart + '$1">($1';
        outputDebugInfo("sReplRange = " + sReplRange);

        var sRemoveRef = sRefStart + '\\d+">\\(?(\\d+)\\)?' + sRefEnd;
        outputDebugInfo("sRemoveRef = " + sRemoveRef);
        var oRemoveRef = new RegExp(sRemoveRef,"g");

        // A Perl regular expression find is used to find 1 or more formula
        // references in a loop which are processed and if needed updated. The
        // formula references are searched and processed always on active file.
        UltraEdit.perlReOn();
        UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.mode=0;
        UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.matchCase=true;
        UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.matchWord=false;
        UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.regExp=true;
        UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.searchDown=true;
        UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.searchInColumn=false;

        UltraEdit.activeDocument.top();
        while (UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.find(sFindRefs))
        {
            nRefsFound++;
            var sReferencesFound = UltraEdit.activeDocument.selection;
            outputDebugInfo("\nsReferencesFound = " + sReferencesFound);

            // Replace - and &#x2013; with or without surrounding whitespaces
            // between > and < (tags) or between ) and ( (reference numbers)
            // by a hash. Hash character is used as it does not exist anymore
            // in the reference sequence string after this replace in contrast
            // to dash character and # is no regular expression character.
            var sRefModified = sReferencesFound.replace(/([)>])\s*(?:-|&#x2013;)\s*([(<])/g,"$1#$2");

            // Remove all whitespaces and commas between the tags.
            sRefModified = sRefModified.replace(/>[\s,]+</g,"><");

            // Replace already existing rid attribute values with a range
            // by rid attribute value with a single reference number.
            sRefModified = sRefModified.replace(/\d+-\d+\">\(?(\d+)\)?/g,'$1">($1)');

            // Convert a reference number range like (5)#(10) into a complete
            // reference range like <xref ref-type="disp-formula" rid="deqn5">
            // (5)</xref>#<xref ref-type="disp-formula" rid="deqn10">(10)</xref>
            sRefModified = sRefModified.replace(/\)#\(?(\d+)/g,sReplRange);
            outputDebugInfo("sRefModified (1) = " + sRefModified);

            // Remove the reference start and end tags to get just the reference
            // single numbers and reference number ranges separated by comma.
            sRefModified = sRefModified.replace(oRemoveRef,"$1,");

            // Insert a comma after each hash character used to mark a range.
            sRefModified = sRefModified.replace(/#/g,"#,");

            // Remove the comma at end of the string.
            sRefModified = sRefModified.substr(0,sRefModified.length-1);
            outputDebugInfo("sRefModified (2) = " + sRefModified);

            // Split up the reference numbers and reference ranges
            // for cross-checking them with the formula identifiers.
            var asReferences = sRefModified.split(",");

            // Convert the number strings into integer numbers and replace
            // also the ranges by appropriate sequences of integer numbers.
            var nRefNumber;
            var anRefNumbers = new Array();
            for (nRefIndex = 0; nRefIndex < asReferences.length; nRefIndex++)
            {
                if (asReferences[nRefIndex] != '#')
                {
                    nRefNumber = parseInt(asReferences[nRefIndex],10);
                    anRefNumbers.push(nRefNumber);
                }
                else
                {
                    var nEndNumber = parseInt(asReferences[++nRefIndex],10);
                    while (nRefNumber < nEndNumber) anRefNumbers.push(++nRefNumber);
                }
            }
            outputDebugInfo("anRefNumbers     = " + anRefNumbers.join(","));

            // Append to the array the value 0 to end any sequence always
            // with in the next loop processing the formula references.
            anRefNumbers.push(0);

            /* Rebuilt the reference(s) by putting together as much formula
                references as possible.

                The base rule for putting a sequence of references together
                is: The reference numbers are one after the other with each
                reference number being +1 of previous reference number and
                no gap between.

                There are three types of ranges:

            1. A reference number range within a single reference because the
                formula identifiers are already put together. E.g. there is

                    <disp-formula id="deqn2-6">...</formula>

                and the reference is

                    <xref ref-type="disp-formula" rid="deqn2-6">(3)&#x2013;(5)</xref>

                It is possible for this type of a range that end number is
                just start number plus 1, for example

                <xref ref-type="disp-formula" rid="deqn2-6">(5)&#x2013;(6)</xref>

            2. A formula reference range because the formula identifiers
                are still separated. For example there are

                    <disp-formula id="deqn7">...</formula>
                    <disp-formula id="deqn8">...</formula>
                    <disp-formula id="deqn9">...</formula>

                and the matching reference range is

                    <xref ref-type="disp-formula" rid="deqn7">(7)</xref>
                    <xref ref-type="disp-formula" rid="deqn8"/>&#x2013;
                    <xref ref-type="disp-formula" rid="deqn9">(9)</xref>

            3. The third range type is a combination of first and second like

                    <xref ref-type="disp-formula" rid="deqn2-6">(3)</xref>
                    <xref ref-type="disp-formula" rid="deqn7"/>
                    <xref ref-type="disp-formula" rid="deqn8"/>&#x2013;
                    <xref ref-type="disp-formula" rid="deqn9">(9)</xref>

                But not put together with a dash is a sequence of exactly
                2 references with different formula identifiers for first
                and second reference like

                    <disp-formula id="deqn7">...</formula>
                    <disp-formula id="deqn8">...</formula>

                referenced with

                    <xref ref-type="disp-formula" rid="deqn7">(7)</xref>,
                    <xref ref-type="disp-formula" rid="deqn8">(8)</xref>
            */

            var nFormulaStart   = -1;
            var nFormulaEnd     = -1;
            var nReferenceStart = -1;
            var nReferenceEnd   = -1;
            var nPreviousNumber = -1;

            nRefIndex = 0;
            sRefModified = "";

            while(true)    // This loop is exited when a reference number
            {              // with the value 0 is loaded from the array.
                var bFormulaFound = false;
                nRefNumber = anRefNumbers[nRefIndex];

                if(nRefNumber > 0)
                {
                    // Find the matching formula identifier for this reference.
                    nFormulaIndex = 0;
                    do
                    {
                        if ((nRefNumber >= anFormulas[nFormulaIndex][0]) &&
                             (nRefNumber <= anFormulas[nFormulaIndex][1]))
                        {
                            bFormulaFound = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    while(++nFormulaIndex < anFormulas.length);
                }

                // Is there no formula matching the reference number or is the
                // current reference number not +1 of previous reference number
                // and the reference is not the first one of a possible range?
                if((!bFormulaFound || (nRefNumber != (nPreviousNumber+1))) && (nPreviousNumber > 0))
                {
                    // Append single or start formula reference.
                    if (nFormulaStart >= 0)
                    {
                        // Append a comma and a space if the rebuilt
                        // reference string is not empty anymore.
                        if (sRefModified.length != 0) sRefModified += ", ";

                        sRefModified += sRefStart + anFormulas[nFormulaStart][0];
                        if (anFormulas[nFormulaStart][0] != anFormulas[nFormulaStart][1])
                        {
                            sRefModified += "-" + anFormulas[nFormulaStart][1];
                        }
                        sRefModified += '">(' + nReferenceStart + ')'

                        // Is there a reference range processing in progress?
                        if(nFormulaEnd >= 0)
                        {
                            // Is this a reference range of first type?
                            if (nFormulaStart == nFormulaEnd)
                            {
                                sRefModified += '&#x2013;(' + nReferenceEnd + ')';
                            }

                            // Are there only 2 references and they don't reference the
                            // same formula identifier, interpret them separated with
                            // a comma and not as formula reference range with a dash.
                            else if ((nReferenceStart+1) == nReferenceEnd)
                            {
                                sRefModified += sRefEnd + ", " + sRefStart + anFormulas[nFormulaEnd][0];
                                if (anFormulas[nFormulaEnd][0] != anFormulas[nFormulaEnd][1])
                                {
                                    sRefModified += "-" + anFormulas[nFormulaEnd][1];
                                }
                                sRefModified += '">(' + nReferenceEnd + ')';
                            }

                            else  // More than 2 references with different
                            {     // start and end formula identifiers.
                                sRefModified += sRefEnd;

                                // Append the empty formula references between start and
                                // end reference number depending on existing formulas.
                                var nSequenceRef = anFormulas[nFormulaStart][1];
                                while (++nSequenceRef < anFormulas[nFormulaEnd][0])
                                {
                                    for(var nSequenceIndex = 0; nSequenceIndex < anFormulas.length; nSequenceIndex++)
                                    {
                                        if ((nSequenceRef >= anFormulas[nSequenceIndex][0]) &&
                                             (nSequenceRef <= anFormulas[nSequenceIndex][1]))
                                        {
                                            sRefModified += sRefStart + anFormulas[nSequenceIndex][0];
                                            if (anFormulas[nSequenceIndex][0] != anFormulas[nSequenceIndex][1])
                                            {
                                                nSequenceRef = anFormulas[nSequenceIndex][1];
                                                sRefModified += "-" + nSequenceRef;
                                            }
                                            sRefModified += '"/>';
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                // Append end formula reference.
                                sRefModified += '&#x2013;' + sRefStart + anFormulas[nFormulaEnd][0];
                                if (anFormulas[nFormulaEnd][0] != anFormulas[nFormulaEnd][1])
                                {
                                    sRefModified += "-" + anFormulas[nFormulaEnd][1];
                                }
                                sRefModified += '">(' + nReferenceEnd + ')';
                            }
                            nFormulaEnd   = -1;
                            nReferenceEnd = -1;
                        }
                        nFormulaStart   = -1;
                        nReferenceStart = -1;
                        sRefModified += sRefEnd;
                    }
                }

                // Are all reference numbers in array processed?
                if (nRefNumber < 1) break;

                // Is there no formula for the current formula reference number?
                if (!bFormulaFound)
                {
                    // This case should never occur, but must be nevertheless
                    // taken into account to avoid corruption of file content.

                    // Append a comma and a space if the rebuilt
                    // reference string is not empty anymore.
                    if (sRefModified.length != 0) sRefModified += ", ";

                    // Append a formula reference like when the formula would really exist.
                    sRefModified += sRefStart + nRefNumber + '">(' + nRefNumber + ')' + sRefEnd;
                    nPreviousNumber = -1;

                    // Output a warning message to output window and make the output
                    // window visible if not already visible on running the script.
                    if (UltraEdit.outputWindow.visible == false)
                    {
                        UltraEdit.outputWindow.showWindow(true);
                    }
                    UltraEdit.outputWindow.write("WARNING: Found no formula for formula reference " + nRefNumber);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Is the current reference number +1 of previous number?
                    if (++nPreviousNumber == nRefNumber)
                    {
                        nReferenceEnd = nRefNumber;
                        nFormulaEnd = nFormulaIndex;
                    }
                    else  // First reference of a possible new range.
                    {
                        nPreviousNumber = nRefNumber;
                        nReferenceStart = nRefNumber;
                        nFormulaStart = nFormulaIndex;
                    }
                }
                nRefIndex++;   // Next reference from array of references.
            }

            if (sRefModified != sReferencesFound)
            {
                nRefsModified++;
                // Overwrite the found reference sequence by rebuilt string.
                UltraEdit.activeDocument.write(sRefModified);
                outputDebugInfo("sRefModified (3) = " + sRefModified);
            }
        }

        UltraEdit.activeDocument.top();
        UltraEdit.messageBox("Number of reference sequences found / modified: " + nRefsFound + " / " + nRefsModified);
    }
}
```

Let's see if somebody on Stack Overflow rewrites this JavaScript code with some UltraEdit extensions as VB.Net code for your company for free.

Comment: firstly, I don't have a UltraEdit forum account, so your mistaking me with someone else, (though the task you described in the forum is nearly identical to mine) and lastly, I did not asked anyone build me the program for free, I had a process in mind to complete the task but was struggling to complete it, so I posted the code that I've tried and asked if anyone can help me point out what am I doing wrong with the code and not asking to build me the entire program, so chill out dude..